# Response code for success not being handled in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to handle error codes thrown by the asp.net web api application. It works fine then record exist and error code 409 is thrown but doesnt work when response code 200 is thrown in case of success. The debug point never hits the catch block in case of success and result object in the save method is null and hence does not run inside   if (result) block. How do i display the sucess message. Previously my asp.net web api was returning IHttpActionResult and the if (result) block executed in case of success.

Asp.net web api

```
[HttpPost]
        [SkipTokenAuthorization]
        [Route("api/classificationoverrides/create")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Create(ClassificationItemViewModelCreate model)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            var mgrClassificationService = GetService<MGR_STRT_CLASSIFICATION>();

            var isExists = mgrClassificationService.Where(x =>
                x.MANAGERSTRATEGYID == model.ManagerStrategyId && x.PRODUCT_ID == model.ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (isExists == null)
            {
               var mgrClassficationOverride = new MGR_STRT_CLASSIFICATION();
                if (model != null)
                {
                    mgrClassficationOverride.PRODUCT_ID = model.ProductId;
                    mgrClassficationOverride.LEGACY_STRATEGY_ID = model.LegacyStrategyId;
                    mgrClassficationOverride.STRATEGY_ID = model.StrategyId;
                    mgrClassficationOverride.MANAGERSTRATEGY_TYPE_ID = model.ManagerStrategyTypeId;
                    mgrClassficationOverride.MANAGERSTRATEGYID = model.ManagerStrategyId;

                    mgrClassficationOverride = mgrClassificationService.Create(mgrClassficationOverride);
                }
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                 response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "The item already exists");
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Angular

```
Save() {

        if (this.ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities.ID === 0) {
            this.Error = '';
            this.classificationOverrideService
                .createClassificationOverrideDetails(this.ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities)
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        this.ClassficationOverrideDetailsEvent.next('init');
                        this.notify.success('Classification Overrides Successfully Created');
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    if (err.status === 200) {
                        this.notify.error('Classification Overrides Successfully Created');
                    } else if (err.status !== 409) {
                        this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While Updating Classification Overrides Details');
                    } else if (err.status === 409) {
                        this.notify.error('Product already exists for this Manager Strategy');
                    }
                });
        }
```

Service

```
import { defer as observableDefer } from 'rxjs';
import { refCount, publishReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response, URLSearchParams, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers, RequestOptions, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Manager360CommonService } from './mgr360.common.service';
import { IClassificationOverride } from '../classification-overrides/classification-override.interface';


@Injectable()
export class ClassificationOverrideService {

        constructor(
                private mgr360CommonService: Manager360CommonService
        ) { }


        getClassificationOverrideDetails(mgrStrategyId: number) {
                return this.mgr360CommonService.httpGet('/api/classificationoverrides/Details/' + mgrStrategyId);
              }

        getClassificationDetails(Id: number) {
                return this.mgr360CommonService.httpGet('/api/classificationoverrides/classificationdetails/' + Id);
              }


        updateClassificationOverrideDetails(classificationOverride: IClassificationOverride) {
                return this.mgr360CommonService.httpPut('/api/classificationoverrides/update', JSON.stringify(classificationOverride));
            }

        createClassificationOverrideDetails(classificationOverride: IClassificationOverride) {
               return this.mgr360CommonService.httpPostAsync('/api/classificationoverrides/create', JSON.stringify(classificationOverride));
            }

        deleteClassificationOverrideDetails(Id: number) {
                return this.mgr360CommonService.httpDelete('/api/classificationoverrides/delete/' + Id);
             }

}
```

common service

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Options } from 'selenium-webdriver/firefox';
import { NotifyService } from '../utilities/notify.service';

const httpPostOptions = {

    headers:
        new HttpHeaders(
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            }),
    withCredentials: true,
};

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Manager360CommonService {

    webApiLocation = this.getApiLocation();

    private getApiLocation() {
        const port = location.port ? ':56888' : '';
        return location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + port;
    }

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

     httpGetAsync(url: string) {

            return this.httpClient.get(this.webApiLocation + url, httpPostOptions)
                .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
                    return response;
                }))
                .toPromise()
                .catch((error: any) => {
                    this.onError(error);
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                });
        }
}
```

Comment: The controll will not go to the catch() block because the the response code is 200 (means "ok"). It does not indicate an error on the request. You have to check the status code in the if (result) { ...} block like if(result.status === 200)

Comment: I am sorry, I am not aware of `httpPostAsync` which eventually needs an HttpContent. I had given an answer considering you would be using `HttpClient`. But yeah, as said in the comment above, your control will not go to catch if it is a success response

Comment: I have just updated the code. I am using httpclient

Comment: @Tom Your `httpPostOptions` will will contain `{observe: 'response'}`, add it there and log the result to see how you will access the contents, status, etc

Answer (score 0):

Your app will not run the code from `catch` function if you get a response with a response status `2xx`.

If you want to show the message if you get `2xx` response you need to place

```
this.notify.success('Classification Overrides Successfully Created');
```

outside of `if(result)` block.

If you want to show the message depending on the successful status code (`2xx`), you should send the request with the request option `{observe: 'response'}` and then check for status code in `then` function

This is the code for the first case:

```
Save() {

        if (this.ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities.ID === 0) {
            this.Error = '';
            this.classificationOverrideService
                .createClassificationOverrideDetails(this.ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities)
                .then((result) => {
                    this.notify.success('Classification Overrides Successfully Created');
                    if (result) {
                        this.ClassficationOverrideDetailsEvent.next('init');

                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    if (err.status !== 409) {
                        this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While Updating Classification Overrides Details');
                    } else if (err.status === 409) {
                        this.notify.error('Product already exists for this Manager Strategy');
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: Hi Dusan, I have just updated the most with bit more code. Where do i set {observe: 'response'}

Comment: I need the second case scenario because i need to execute  this.ClassficationOverrideDetailsEvent.next('init'); based on sucess

Comment: if the app run `then` function that means that the response was successful, tell me do you make the difference for status codes `200` and `201` or that is the same for you?

Comment: Just like @xyz has said, you should put `{observe: 'response'}` in `httpPostOptions`

Comment: Basically if the record is created or updated it would return 200 i presume

Comment: If i use the first approach then what is the use of checking the if(result). I need to call   this.ClassficationOverrideDetailsEvent.next('init'); if the sucess

Comment: With that check, you are checking if the result is not null or undefined. You know the response is successful when the app runs `then` function

Comment: but as per the first case scenario the result is always null even if success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192362/discussion-between-tom-and-dusan-radovanovic).